# ln: create relative symlink to a relative symlink

Tags: symlink, coreutils, ln

I want to create a relative symlink pointing to a relative symlink, not to the relative symlink's target. It seems that when creating a relative symlink `ln` resolves `TARGET` instead of pointing to the actual `TARGET`. Can this process be skipped? In the example below, I would want `rsym-to-existing-rsym.txt` to point to `rsym-to-target.txt`, not to `target.txt`.

When I create a symlink to not-yet-existing symlink it works (`rsym-to-future-rsym.txt` -> `future-rsym-to-target.txt` -> `target.txt` chain in the example below).

## Example

```
# Create initial structure
$ mkdir -p temp
$ touch temp/target.txt

# Now, create relative symlinks
$ ln -s -r temp/target.txt temp/rsym-to-target.txt
$ ln -s -r temp/rsym-to-target.txt temp/rsym-to-existing-rsym.txt
# Note that at this point temp/future-rsym-to-target.txt doesn't exist yet
$ ln -s -r temp/future-rsym-to-target.txt temp/rsym-to-future-rsym.txt
$ ln -s -r temp/target.txt temp/future-rsym-to-target.txt

$ tree -F temp/
# Note that rsym-to-existing-rsym.txt points to target.txt, not to rsym-to-target.txt
temp/
├── future-rsym-to-target.txt -> target.txt
├── rsym-to-existing-rsym.txt -> target.txt
├── rsym-to-future-rsym.txt -> future-rsym-to-target.txt
├── rsym-to-target.txt -> target.txt
└── target.txt

# Maybe the tools I'm using are just nice to me and resolve final paths?
# No, when I delete rsym-to-target.txt symlink rsym-to-existing-rsym.txt still points to target.txt
$ rm temp/rsym-to-target.txt
 tree -F temp/
temp/
├── future-rsym-to-target.txt -> target.txt
├── rsym-to-existing-rsym.txt -> target.txt
├── rsym-to-future-rsym.txt -> future-rsym-to-target.txt
└── target.txt
```

Comment: Why are you using `-r` with `ln`? Can't you just do `ln -s rsym-to-target.txt temp/rsym-to-existing-rsym.txt`?

Comment: No, `-r` makes things easier when working across containers, variable paths, mount points etc.

Comment: Well, since using `-r` will cause the target of the link to be resolved, and since using `-n` or `-P` does not stop this from happening, there's really nothing you can do about it, other than to stop using `-r`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A plain `ln -s` treats its target as a string. It doesn't care whether that string happens to be a path to an existing file.

The GNU extension `ln -sr` treats its target as a filesystem location. It needs to dereference directories in the target, because otherwise the resulting actual target would be wrong:

```
mkdir /tmp/demo /tmp/foreign
cd /tmp/demo
mkdir child
ln -s -r foo child/foo        # -> ../foo
ln -s /tmp/foreign elsewhere
ln -s -r foo elsewhere/foo    # -> ../demo/foo ­­— not ../foo
```

This could have been implemented without dereferencing the final component of the path, but it wasn't.

The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ln-invocation.html) explains how to obtain a link that's relative to the given directory. Instead of using `ln -r`, call [`realpath`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/realpath-invocation.html) (which is also part of GNU coreutils) to construct the relative path. The invocation is different depending on whether you're passing the link name or the name of a directory where the link will be created.

If `$dir` is a directory:

```
ln -s -- "$(realpath -m --relative-to "$dir" -- "$target")" "$dir"
```

If `$linkname` is the path to the link to create:

```
ln -s -- "$(realpath -m --relative-to "$(dirname -- "$linkname")" -- "$target")" "$linkname"
```